# Accessing Android App using Perl

Tags: android, linux, perl, apk, mechanize

Is there a way to access an APK / Android App using Perl like the way www::mechanize does it for websites? (like having an emulator running the app under Linux and parsing App screens like websites using www::mechanize?)

What would be the best way here?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can access web based android apps using perl
You need a web debugger like charles to debug the URLs

You can follow the steps from the following url 
https://community.tealiumiq.com/t5/Tealium-for-Android/Setting-up-Charles-to-Proxy-your-Android-Device/ta-p/5121

After the proxy setup completes web relative post or get calls can be viewed on proxy debugger

The same can be used to traverse through the app you want to using www::mechanize